# How can I open a Bootstrap modal when an input is clicked?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm working with Bootstrap and I have a search form and a modal. I want my model to open up when I click on the search form. The modals I found online were only working with a button but I don't want my model to open up with a button. Is there a way to make my modal work with input form?

I looked here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

[image]

My search form code:

```
        <div class="input-box">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I fixed my tags and posted the solution that worked for me. @isherwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that worked for me:

```
<!-- Search Form -->
<div class="input-box">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>

   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below

In your search form

```
<div class="input-box" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </div>
```

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

<h1> my sample modal content</h1>
  
</div>
```

the most important thing is the `class="modal"` and the id of the modal `id="exampleModal"` , you target the model in the input field using `data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"` classes inside the `search form`

Comment: I tried this code but when I clicked on the input form the modal didn't open up. I changed the code a little bit now it's working. Thanks! @Bernietechy